# Grant ACL Network access, Grant ACL Network access

Tags: oracle

I have created ACL rules for network access:

```
EXEC DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL (acl => 'ACL_FILE_1.xml', description => 'ACL_FILE_1', principal => 'USER_1', is_grant => TRUE, privilege => 'connect', start_date => null, end_date => null); 
EXEC DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl => 'ACL_FILE_1.xml',principal => 'USER_1',is_grant  => true,privilege => 'connect');
EXEC DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL ( acl => 'ACL_FILE_1.xml', host => '*', lower_port => NULL, upper_port => NULL);
```

After this, i can connect with no problem with de SYS user, but i can't connect with the USER_1 user.

I run this:

```
select SYS.UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_ADDRESS('MY_IP') FROM DUAL;
```

And i receive this error:

```
ORA-24247: acceso de red denegado por la lista de control de acceso (ACL)
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_INADDR", línea 19
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_INADDR", línea 40
ORA-06512: en línea 1
24247. 00000 -  "network access denied by access control list (ACL)"
*Cause:    No access control list (ACL) has been assigned to the target
           host or the privilege necessary to access the target host has not
           been granted to the user in the access control list.
*Action:   Ensure that an access control list (ACL) has been assigned to
           the target host and the privilege necessary to access the target
           host has been granted to the user.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Seriously, can you please review your title, and if it says the same thing twice, edit it to fix it? That's the least effort that's required on your part when you post for free help.

Comment: You also need to add:    privilege => 'resolve'

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl (
    acl         => 'ftp_send.xml',
    description => 'Allow report to be send',
    principal   => 'USER_1',
    is_grant    => TRUE,
    privilege   => 'connect'
    );
    commit;
end;

begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege (
  acl       => 'ftp_send.xml',
  principal => 'USER_1',
  is_grant  => TRUE,
  privilege => 'resolve'
  );
  commit;
end;

begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl(
  acl  => 'ftp_send.xml',
  host => 'MI_IP'
  );
  commit;
end;
```

Thanks for the coments.